# How do i retrieve image from mysql and display on jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, storage

What method should I use to retrieve and display my image which is store in mysql with the datatype longblob. As for string I simply use 
(Example: rs.getString("foodname"))

but waht is the datatype to use for the image as I declare it as object in java class. So should i use ?

rs.getObject("image")

Thank you

Comment: use `getBytes()` convert later

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to get it as blob and convert this binary data to image [see this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/GetBLOBdatafromresultset.htm)